# Automake and external conditional sources

Tags: makefile, autotools, configure, automake

How to properly define external conditional sources in a `Makefile.am` file?

As an example, in GNU MPFR, we currently have in [`src/Makefile.am`](https://gforge.inria.fr/scm/viewvc.php/mpfr/trunk/src/Makefile.am?revision=13228&view=markup#l95):

```
if MINI_GMP
nodist_include_HEADERS += $(mini_gmp_path)/mini-gmp.h
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libminigmp.la
nodist_libminigmp_la_SOURCES = $(mini_gmp_path)/mini-gmp.h $(mini_gmp_path)/mini-gmp.c
libmpfr_la_LIBADD += libminigmp.la
endif
```

where `MINI_GMP` is true when `mini_gmp_path` is defined. The goal is to optionally build MPFR against a libminigmp library (mini-gmp), which is itself built with the autotools machinery (same compiler, same options, etc. as MPFR).

Everything seems to work well, except when one does not want to build against mini-gmp. In this case, the generated `configure` script fails with:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating mpfr.pc
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tune/Makefile
config.status: creating src/mparam.h
config.status: creating tools/bench/Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: error: in `/home/vlefevre/software/mpfr':
config.status: error: Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments
    for automatic dependency tracking.  Try re-running configure with the
    '--disable-dependency-tracking' option to at least be able to build
    the package (albeit without support for automatic dependency tracking).
See `config.log' for more details
```

and in the `config.log` file:

```
config.status:19572: executing depfiles commands
config.status:19647: cd src       && sed -e '/# am--include-marker/d' Makefile         | make -f - am--depfiles
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory '/.deps': Permission denied
make: *** [/tmp/GmlvxQJQ:720: /.deps/mini-gmp.Plo] Error 1
```

The reason is that the generated `src/Makefile` file contains things like `$(mini_gmp_path)/$(DEPDIR)/mini-gmp.Plo` while `mini_gmp_path` is not defined. But since one does not want to build against mini-gmp, such information about `mini-gmp.Plo` is incorrect, i.e. mini-gmp files should completely be ignored for automatic dependency tracking when `MINI_GMP` is false.

As a workaround, we currently define `mini_gmp_path` to `.` in `configure.ac` when one does not build against mini-gmp, so that the `$(mini_gmp_path)/$(DEPDIR)` directory exists, avoiding a `configure` failure. But this is not a clean solution, which might interfere with `mini-gmp.{c,h}` files that could be added in the MPFR source tree. The solution should just get rid of `mini-gmp.Plo` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think incorporating external sources into your build is a supported use case.  It certainly does not make much sense to me.  Nevertheless, possible alternatives include

- Bundle the minigmp sources with your project (their use can still be optional).  This has the additional advantage that you can be sure you provide a compatible version.
- Add standard `make` rules to create the minigmp sources in some existing directory inside the project by copying them from `$(mini_gmp_path)`.  You may also want to list the minigmp sources (in the internal directory) among your `BUILT_SOURCES`.

  ```
  if MINI_GMP
    noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libminigmp.la
    libmpfr_la_LIBADD += libminigmp.la

    nodist_libminigmp_la_SOURCES = minigmp/mini-gmp.h minigmp/mini-gmp.c
    BUILT_SOURCES = $(nodist_libminigmp_la_SOURCES)

    # Are you want the mini-gmp header to be installed?
    nodist_include_HEADERS += minigmp/mini-gmp.h
  else
    noinst_LTLIBRARIES =
    BUILT_SOURCES =
  endif

  minigmp/mini-gmp.c: $(mini_gmp_path)/mini-gmp.c
      cp $< $@

  minigmp/mini-gmp.h: $(mini_gmp_path)/mini-gmp.h
      cp $< $@
  ```

  Automake should not subject such rules to the same level of analysis that it does the variables that are meaningful to it.
- Put the onus on the project builder to build and install a compatible version of minigmp.  Link against that.

Comment: (1) cannot be done because several incompatible mini-gmp versions are supported, and the user may want to provide his own. (2) doesn't solve the problem as `mini-gmp.Plo` is still created (and used by `make`, according to `strace`) when one doesn't build against mini-gmp; moreover the copy would have to be forced (not based on timestamp) to be able to change the mini-gmp version. (3) is partly what we wanted to avoid (one goal is to be able to modify mini-gmp and rebuild MPFR easily).